# How to print data read from text file which at different function

Tags: c++

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English.

The thing that I would like to ask is that how do I print the data read from a text file which is at different function.

The `load()` function is defined as below.

```
void Picture::load(string filename) throw(string)
{
int x,y;
string line;

fstream infile(filename.c_str(), fstream::in);

if (infile.is_open())
{
    if (!getline(infile, line))
        throw string("Unable to read the first line.");

    istringstream iss(line);

    if (!(iss >> height >> width))
        throw string("First line does not consist of two integers.");

    picture = new char*[width];

    for (x=0; x<width; x++)
        picture[x] = new char[height];

    for (y=0; y<height; y++)
    {
        getline(infile,line);

        if (line.length() < width)
            throw string("Line "+convertInt(y+1)+" in picture has an incorrect width.");
        else
            for (x=0; x<width; x++)
                set(x,y,line[x]);
    }

    infile.close();
    }

    else throw string("Unable to open file");
}

void Picture::print()
{
    // This function will print the data read on load function
}
```

How do I relate these 2 functions so I can load and print?

Sorry if this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data as a private member of your class:

```
private std::string data;
void loadAndPrint::load()
{
    in_file.open("infile.txt");
    in_file >> data;
}
void loadAndPrint::print()
{
    ofstream out_file("outfile.txt");
    if(!out_file.is_open()) throw myError;
    out_file << data;
}
```

Comment: I have a private member `char **picture`. Could you refer to my latest edited question on the `load()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the fstream by reference to the second function. That keeps you from having to make a private variable.

Edit:

Without being able to see the entire class, I can't be sure, but it looks like your instructor wants you to use NTCAs for this assignment. Without just giving you the entire answer, take a look at this article and see if it answers your question:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Comment: Well, actually this assignment, my lecturer has defined the load function and also the class which can't be changed. Read my latest edited question. I included the `load()` function which I couldn't change.

Comment: So the only thing you can change is the print function and things outside of the class?

Comment: Yes. The thing I'm required to do is complete the methods which is defined. And I have problem on the print the text loaded.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment, my lecturer gave tips on the print. Actually on the `load()` function, the `set(x,y,line[x]);` is the one which stores the character. So I have to complete the `set` function first before printing. Sorry for wasting your time.